# How do I add permissions to an OU using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I can get the OU object like....

```
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(
            "LDAP://domain.com",
            "DOMAIN\\Administrator",
            "Password");
        DirectoryEntry ouEntry = de.Children.Find("OU=my-users,DC=domain,DC=com");
```

But I can't seem to find any classes or libraries to add permissions.  I want to give "MyGroup" permission to create and delete objects in this OU.  I can do this manually in ADSIEdit by selecting the OU and using the Security tab but can't find the equivalent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Test OU,DC=test,DC=com");
DirectorySearcher dsFindOUs = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);

dsFindOUs.Filter = "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)";
dsFindOUs.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
SearchResult oResults = dsFindOUs.FindOne();
DirectoryEntry myOU = oResults.GetDirectoryEntry();

System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference newOwner = new System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("YourDomain", "YourUserName").Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
ActiveDirectoryAccessRule newRule = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(newOwner, ActiveDirectoryRights.GenericAll, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
myOU.ObjectSecurity.SetAccessRule(newRule);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Raymund
http://anyrest.wordpress.com